# 2D SVD and Kabsch algorithm

Tags: math, 2d, svd

I'm implementing [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) in 2D. Result of algo is: translation, rotation, scale. Combaining them and applying on 1st set of points should "align" them to 2nd set of points.
So far my implementation (work-in-progress):

```
    // maps points 'A' onto points 'B'
    public static (Vector2,Matrix2x2,float) Compute( List< Vector2 > pointsA, List< Vector2 > pointsB )
    {
        // scale : ratio of sums of "some" distances, e.g. to "neighbour" or to centroid...
        
        var dsumA = 0f;
        var dsumB = 0f;
        
        for( var i = num; i --> 1; )
        {
            dsumA += ( pointsA[ i ] - pointsA[ i-1 ] ).sqrMagnitude;
            dsumB += ( pointsB[ i ] - pointsB[ i-1 ] ).sqrMagnitude;
        }
        
        if( dsumA == 0f || dsumB == 0f )
            return (Vector2.zero,Matrix2x2.IDENTITY,1f);
        
        var scale = MathF32.Sqrt( dsumB / dsumA );
        
        // rotation : based on singular-value-decomposition of cross-covariance matrix of given point-sets...
        
        var centroidA = Vector2.zero;
        var centroidB = Vector2.zero;
        
        for( int i = num; i --> 0; ) // centroids
        {
            centroidA += pointsA[ i ];
            centroidB += pointsB[ i ];
        }
        
        var invNum = 1f / num;
        
        centroidA *= invNum;
        centroidB *= invNum;
        
        var cc = new Matrix2x2();
        
        for( var i = num; i --> 0; ) // cross-covariance matrix : transposed( move-to-origin( A ) ) * move-to-origin( B )
        {
            var a = pointsA[ i ] - centroidA;
            var b = pointsB[ i ] - centroidB;
            
            cc.m00 += a.x * b.x;   cc.m01 += a.x * b.y;
            cc.m10 += a.y * b.x;   cc.m11 += a.y * b.y;
        }
        
        (var u, _, var v) = cc.SingularValueDecomposition();
        
        u.Transpose();
        
        if( cc.GetDeterminant() < 0f ) // handling special "reflection" case
        {
            v.m01 *= -1f;
            v.m11 *= -1f;
        }
        
        var rotation = v * u;
        
        // transition : difference of centroids...
        
        var translation = centroidB - rotation * ( centroidA * scale );
        
        // result...
        
        return (translation,rotation,scale);
    }
```

To compute rotation matrix you need to compute SVD (singular value decomposition) of covariance matrix. I'm not "fluent" in math at all :( so I tried few SVD implementations (svd(A) = U * S * V^T) meantioned [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/robust-algorithm-for-2-times-2-svd).

I compared results of "borrowed" implementations with few online SVD calculators. Matrix S is alright **but almost all entries in U and V have different signs**. I tried 2 or 3 different implementations so I assume
that problem is somewhere else - probably in construction of covariance matrix :(, but I can't spot the bug.

1. Any notes for implementation of Kabsh itself ?
2. Or how can I fix SVD (those wrong signs in U and V) ?

I noticed that determinant of my covariance matrix is negative. Could it be this?

Many thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE #1**

For SVD I'm using following implementation (with others I got small errors - few degrees in final rotation).

```
    public (Matrix2x2,Matrix2x2,Matrix2x2) SingularValueDecomposition()
    {
        Matrix2x2 u;
        Matrix2x2 s;
        Matrix2x2 v;
        
        s.m00 = ( MathF32.Hypot( m00 - m11, m01 + m10 ) +
                  MathF32.Hypot( m00 + m11, m01 - m10 ) ) * 0.5f;
        s.m01 = 0f;
        s.m10 = 0f;
        s.m11 = MathF32.Abs( s.m00 - MathF32.Hypot( m00 - m11, m10 + m01 ));
        
        v.m10 = ( s.m00 > s.m11 ) ? MathF32.Sin(( MathF32.ATan2( 2f * ( m00 * m01 + m10 * m11 ), m00 * m00 - m01 * m01 + m10 * m10 - m11 * m11 )) / 2f ) : 0f;
        v.m00 = MathF32.Sqrt( 1f - v.m10 * v.m10 );
        v.m01 = -v.m10;
        v.m11 = +v.m00;
        
        u.m00 = s.m00 != 0f ? ( m00 * v.m00 + m01 * v.m10 ) / s.m00 :     1f;
        u.m10 = s.m00 != 0f ? ( m10 * v.m00 + m11 * v.m10 ) / s.m00 :     0f;
        u.m01 = s.m11 != 0f ? ( m00 * v.m01 + m01 * v.m11 ) / s.m11 : -u.m10;
        u.m11 = s.m11 != 0f ? ( m10 * v.m01 + m11 * v.m11 ) / s.m11 : +u.m00;
        
        return (u,s,v);
    }
```

Yet still those signs in U and V are different from decompositions I got from few online SVD calculators.

**UPDATE #2**

I'm able to fixup rotation (rotation angle) to align points properly but "fixup" differs based on input point-sets.
Sometimes helps 180-angle. Sometimes 360-angle... and even 180+angle for some poit-sets :(. Mentioned / corrected angle is extracted from computed 'rotation' matrix.

This "correction" is needed for all implementations of SVD I tried so far ([3 or 4](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/robust-algorithm-for-2-times-2-svd)) so **I'm "starting" to think that problem lies somewhere else**...

Translation and scale seams to work properly. With "fixed" rotation I'm able to align 'A' to 'B' properly.

**UPDATE #3**

I tested if SVD works by checking if U * S * Vt gets me original covariance-matrix and it does.

I found one problem in setupping covariance-matrix (fixed, code above updated) but still getting wrong rotation :(.
Also I fixed translation.

Ahhhh... so simple algorithm yet I can't beat it :)

**UPDATE #4... FINAL ONE**

Sorry everyone, I finally found the problem :). At some point (in my test app) order of points in one of input set changed. I corrected it and it "magically" started to work. I updated / polished the code above for future generations :).

Comment: There are a few degrees of freedom in constructing SVDs. Does the rotation you get make sense? Maybe try with some data that don't require scaling first. Are the points ordered equivalently, i.e., p[i] corresponds to q[i]?

Comment: For now yes (in my test app), the order of points in both sets correspond, but I can't rely on it. Also I would like "general" 2x2 SVD implementation. In my posted update I found quite precise implementation of SVD, again at least in my test app... but to make Kabsch algo work I must "flip" computed rotation : 180 - rotation.